# How to filter best related and create in one query?

Tags: python, django, atomic, select-for-update

I want to select best related object and save new one in one query to avoid race condition. Is it possible? 
Does select_for_update solve this problem?

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    maker_order = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
                                       related_name='taker_order')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.maker_order = Order.objects.filter(maker_order__isnull=True, taker_order__isnull=True,
                                                price__lte=self.price
                                                ).order_by('price').first()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes you could use `select_for_update` and `transaction.atomic` to avoid race condition. That mean you have to wrap your save method inside an atomic transaction context, then `select_for_update`

Comment: What happens in second thread when lock is released? Will django repeat query or return row, that was locked?

Comment: Actually it still continue but only perform the calculation when the lock released. [This article](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2) describe very clear about the issue and how to handle it in Django, there is another way that also works, so give it a try.